# Update existing field collections with Migrate module

Tags: migrations, entities

How can I update existing field collection entities using Migrate module? I wasn't able to find any examples at [the official documentation page](https://www.drupal.org/node/1900640), nor anywhere else.

When I'm migrating nodes, I can do something like:

```
$this->addFieldMapping('nid', 'nid');
$this->systemOfRecord = Migration::DESTINATION;
```

What's the alternative in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no current support in field_collection for this (a destination plugin must explicitly support Migration::DESTINATION, merging mapped fields with pre-existing values for the unmapped fields). I'd suggest submitting a feature request at https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/field_collection.